# $g'(x) = x \sin x$ when $g(x) = \int_0^x t \sin t $ for all $x \in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Can we say by fundamental theorem of calculus that  $g'(x) = x \sin x$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ ? Here $g(x) = \int_0^x t \sin t $.

Comment: If the implication follows the order in your post and not the title, then yes it is true.

Comment: Is it now oaky?@NinadMunshi

Comment: Why would you doubt that? Any specific thoughts behind this? The result is an immediate consequence of Fundamental theorem of calculus. It applies because Integrand is continuous everywhere.

Comment: Actually I know the proof of that when $x \in (0 , \infty)$ . But before proceeding to prove the statement on $(-\infty , 0]$ also , I just wanted to verify that the statement is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Since
$$g(x)=\int_0^x t\sin t dt = F(x) - F(0)$$
where $F = \int f$ and $f = x\sin x$, differentiate both sides to get
$$g'(x) = \big(F(x)-F(0)\big)'_x = F'(x)=f(x)=x\sin x$$